# Error in when Displaying Status with twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

Getting these  error when I run the android application:

Instead of getting the statuses Im getting one status that says "JSON EXCEPTiON".
Im also getting these errors in the elogcat.

01-22 15:39:09.783: E/Twitter(468): Error retrieving tweets
01-22 15:39:09.783: E/Twitter(468): 404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exists.
01-22 15:39:09.783: E/Twitter(468): {"error":"Not found","request":"/1/null/lists/0/statuses.json?page=1"}

This code was working great. But then e I put icons on my listview(The menu before I show the statuses...) . I am getting the error somewhere over here:

Any ideas?

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate the views from XML
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_text_layout, null);
    JSONObject jsonImageText = getItem(position);

ImageView imageview =(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.last_build_stat);
try {
    String date = (String)jsonImageText.get("tweetDate");
    String avatar = (String)jsonImageText.get("avatar");
    imageview.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(avatar));
} catch (JSONException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}


    // Set the text on the TextView
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.job_text);


    try {

        String tweet = (String)jsonImageText.get("tweet");

        String auth = (String)jsonImageText.get("author");

        //String date = (String)jsonImageText.get("tweetDate");

        if (date.length()>0){

            String latest = tweet + "<br><br><i>" + auth + " - " + date + "</i>";
            //String latest = tweet;
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(latest));
        } else {

            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(tweet) + "\n" + Html.fromHtml(auth));
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {

        textView.setText("JSON Exception");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exists. 01-22 15:39:09.783: E/Twitter(468): {"error":"Not found","request":"/1/null/lists/0/statuses.json?page=1"}
```

From this message it is evident that call to Twitter API failing. I would suggest put some print statement before calling Twitter API and print out the URL you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks figured it out My Menu key word needed to be in capital letters..